# SceneKit – Applied CIFilter on SCNNode hides SCNTorus

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, cifilter

I have the following node setup on my scene: 
A container node with child nodes: earth, torus, and moon. I applied to the earth node's filter property the following custom HighlightFilter with CIBloom and CISourceOverCompositing filter for the glow effect:

CIFilter Class (code from awesome blog: [Highlighting SCNNode with Glow](https://badrit.com/blog/2018/5/25/highlighting-scnnode-with-glow#.W93hyi2X_UY))

```
class HighlightFilter: CIFilter {

static let filterName = "highlightFilter"

@objc dynamic var inputImage: CIImage?
@objc dynamic var inputIntensity: NSNumber?
@objc dynamic var inputRadius: NSNumber?

override var outputImage: CIImage? {
    guard let inputImage = inputImage else {
        return nil
    }

    let bloomFilter = CIFilter(name:"CIBloom")!
    bloomFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    bloomFilter.setValue(inputIntensity, forKey: "inputIntensity")
    bloomFilter.setValue(inputRadius, forKey: "inputRadius")

    let sourceOverCompositing = CIFilter(name:"CISourceOverCompositing")!
    sourceOverCompositing.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    sourceOverCompositing.setValue(bloomFilter.outputImage, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")

    return sourceOverCompositing.outputImage
}}
```

I don't understand this invisible rectangle. I assume it is because of the CIFilter SourceOverCompositing which overlays the modified image over the original. But why is the torus hidden and the moon not? 
I added the torus material to the moons'. material property, to see if something is wrong with the material. But still the same, moon is visible, torus is hidden. The moon rotates around with a helperNode as a child to the containerNode.

[image: Moon is in visible, but torus not]
[image: Torus is not visible behind this omninius rectangle]

[image: Scenegraph]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may happen due to two potential problems.

**SOLUTION 1**.

When you're using `CISourceOverCompositing` you need a premultiplied RGBA image (RGB * A) for foreground, where an alpha channel has **the same shape** as the Earth (left picture). But you're having an alpha channel covering all the image (right picture).

If you wanna know what's the shape of Alpha channel in your Earth image – use one of these compositing applications: The Foundry Nuke, Adobe After Effect, Apple Motion, Blackmagic Fusion, etc.

Also, if you want to composite the Moon and the Earth separately, you have to have them as two different images.

[image]

In compositing classical `OVER` operation has the following formula:

```
(RGB_image1 * A_image1) + (RGB_image2 * (1 – A_image1))
```

The first part of this formula is a premultiplied foreground image (the Earth) – RGB1 * A1.

The second part of this formula is a background image with a hole – RGB2 * inverted_A1. You've got the inversion of the alpha channel using (1-A). The background image itself could have only three components – RGB (without A).

Then you add two images together using simple addition operation. If you have several `OVER` operations – the order of these ops is crucial.

**SOLUTION 2**.

It could be due to a `Depth Buffer`. Disable `writesToDepthBuffer` instance property. It is a Boolean value that determines whether SceneKit produces depth information when rendering the material.

```
yourTorusNode.geometry?.materials.first?.writesToDepthBuffer = false
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm struggeling to get a foreground image with an alpha channel which has the same shape as the earth with CIFilter. The graphics, which I use as materials around my earth sphere are .heic graphics. If I see the inputImage in my HighlightFilter class, the ciimage is the earth with a transparent background.

Comment: Use `.png` or `.tiff` with a premultiplied alpha (RGB*A). Do not use three-channels formats such as `.jpeg` or `.heif` (`.heic`).

Comment: I made premultiplied `.png` file for you. See my updated answer (bottom).

Comment: Have you composited my FG with your BG?

Comment: I'm facing still the same behaviour. Scenekit uses premultiplied alpha. Instead of adding a graphic to my material.diffuse property, I assigned a UIColor directly (material.diffuse = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(1.0). Still the same. I tried different filters, for example the CIPhotoEffectMono, still the same problem...

Comment: Could you publish a screen-capture of your Viewer in Xcode? Do you have any planes in 3D space? There might be some occlusion.

Comment: Also, please show me the geometry's hierarchy in left pane.

Comment: I updated my question with the scenegraph. I dont know why every node is untitled?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183064/discussion-between-argeo-and-emanuel-huser).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why this strange behaviour occured, but deleting the following line made it disappear.

self.torus.firstMaterial?.writesToDepthBuffer = false

The writesToDepthBuffer property on the material on the torus was set to false.